# VS2013 hosting on existing azure virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-virtual-machine

When you start a New Project in VS 2013, you can choose to host the project on an Azure Virtual Machine.

The problem is that it seems you can ONLY CREATE a NEW ONE and not host it on an existing virtual machine you might already have.

Or at least, I cannot find the way to do so and cannot find anything on the net that shows me how.

QUESTION:
How can I use my existing Azure Virtual Machine to host an MVC application developed from my desktop??

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you're after, you can simply install and configure IIS, create a virtual and point it to the file system path where you have your production code (you can simply upload it to the server). You would then simply open up the appropriate ports in the Azure interface to allow external access if desired. You're basically just setting up an IIS site that can host your application then uploading the app to the server using something like FTP or web deployment.

-matt

Comment: Not really. My question was ...how come you can CREATE a NEW VM when you start a NEW Project, but NOT USE an EXISTING VM ??

Comment: @matt Not helpful. The OP is asking a totally different question.